# Differentiability of the complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

the complex function is defined $f(z) = \frac{z^3}{|z|^2}$ if $z \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. It is easy to see the function is not differentiable using the Cauchy-Riemann equation, but I struggle to understand why $f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(h)}{h}}$. Could anyone shed some lights?

Comment: Well, if that limit exists then it is - by definition - the derivative of f(z) at z=0. The problem here is not that the limit doesn't exist, but that its value depends on the direction from which h approaches 0. If f was analytic at 0 then the limit would have the same value regardless of how h approached 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With definition of differentiation 
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h^2}{|h|^2}=\left(\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h}{|h|}\right)^2$$
doesn't exist! Consider for instance two cases $h=x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h=x+ix$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck